# typescript err: must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator when using react usereducer hook in context-why?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Im using typescript, not too familiar with and am getting the following err for when I use context and useReducer hook- in particularly for my dispatch method I get this:

```
contextProps must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator.
```

I tried to research it but can't figure out what to do. I imagine its because of  const [state, dispatch] = useContext(GlobalState); and I need to specify something because of the array.
Also, Im getting a ts err for value in

```
  <GlobalState.Provider value={[state, dispatch]}>
```

(see in code below). Somehow when I have it an array, all properties I have defined in ContextProps are missing.
Any help would be so helpful!

```
//context.js file
export interface ProjectProps {
  projects: string[]
}

export interface ContextProps extends ProjectProps {
  show: boolean
  posts: string[]
  //...
}

const initialState = {
  posts: [],
  show: false
  //...
};

export const GlobalState = React.createContext<ContextProps | null>(
  initialState
)

const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "SHOW":
      return { ...state, show: !state.show }

    default:
      return state
  }
}

const Store: React.FC<{ children: React.ReactNode }> = ({children}) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(Reducer, initialState);
  return (
      <GlobalState.Provider value={[state, dispatch]}>
          {children}
      </GlobalState.Provider>
  )
};


const App = () => {
  return (
      <Store>
          <Header/>
          <Blog/>
      </Store>
  );
};

const Blog = () => {

  const [state, dispatch] = useContext(GlobalState);

  return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={dispatch({type: "SHOW"})}></button>
        {state.show ? <p>hello</p> : null }
      </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 3):

There seem to be a few things wrong with the code you've provided.

First off, I would start by adding more typings.
Especially to the parameters and output of `reducer` and to the `const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);` (note: I assume that `reducer` was meant to be lowercase here, eventhough it's `Reducer` in your code sample.

Next, I think there is a problem with the definition of your context compared to how you're using it.
If you want to provide both the `state` and `dispatch` to your Provider (as indicated by `<GlobalState.Provider value={[state, dispatch]}>`, then I would expect your context definition to look more like this:

```
interface Context {
  state: {
    show: boolean;
    posts: string[];
    //...
  };
  dispatch: React.Dispatch<any>; // I don't know what any should be in your case
}
```

Note, that:

- Your provider would change to:
  `<GlobalState.Provider value={{state, dispatch}}>`.
- The usage would change to: `const {state, dispatch} = useContext(GlobalState);`

*If you do want to use `[state, dispatch]` as the output of your context, then you should use a type like `type Context = [{show: boolean; posts: string[];}, React.Dispatch<any>]` instead of an `interface`.*

Finally, an error like `... must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator.` usually means that you're iterating (using `for`, `while`, ...) through an object that isn't a type that can be iterated. An example of a type that can be iterated would be an `Array`.
If you'd like more guidance on this last error, then it would help if you specified exactly where this error is occuring.

Comment: Thank you. I get the [Symbol.iterator] wherever I use context (--> const [state, dispatch] = useContext(GlobalState) for state AND/OR dispatch. Also, I didn't add more typings as it wasn't relevant for my question but thank you. Also I tried your context definition but it only gives me errs

Comment: Actually, now that I think about it `const [state, dispatch] = useContext(GlobalState)`. You're destructing an array here into 2 variables. But `GlobalState` gets its type from `React.createContext<ContextProps | null>(
  initialState
)`. Which is not an array and cannot be iterated over.